# How to copy projects in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried copying my Android Studio project but every time I do that it gives me errors. I read other questions and answers on this topics but none of this helped me.

When I copy a project and try to run it on the emulator it gives the following error:

> "Installation failed with message Invalid File:
>   C:...\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk. It
>   is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing
>   version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing."

According to answers on similar questions, it should help to perform a 'clean project'. When I do this, the emulator starts but stops starting the app with a runtime error:

> "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{nl.assortimens.hardlooptrainingapp/nl.assortimens.hardlooptrainingapp.MainMenuActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "nl.assortimens.hardlooptrainingapp.MainMenuActivity" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/nl.assortimens.hardlooptrainingapp-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/nl.assortimens.hardlooptrainingapp-1/lib/x86,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]"

How can I copy projects without errors or what should I do to fix those errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to delete the `intermediates` folder and `rebuild` the project, if not delete the `build` folder and `rebuild` again

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem. I tried deleting the intermediates folder, but I needed to delete the entire build folder to make it work

Answer (score 0):

go to run-> rebuild project  and should work correct

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the build.gradle file, and settings.gradle file. Then rebuild. Hope this gives your problem.